# $T$ Invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, invariance

Please help me to write a step by step solution to this problem:

Let $T$ be a linear operator defined on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. If $W$ is a $T$ invariant subspace with $V = \mathrm{im}(T) \oplus W$, then show that W must be $N(T)$ (the null space of $T$).

I am getting an intuition but am at a loss as how to write that formally...

Comment: What is $(+)W$?

Comment: @ElChapo I guess it means $\oplus$, and maybe $R(T)=\text{im}(T)$?

Comment: @ElChapo :user160738 is absolutely right.

Comment: @Qwerty What does $\oplus$ mean in this context? Is the finite dimensional vector space equipped with a scalar product, and it means the orthogonal sum, or is it the direct sum?

Comment: @Qwerty, what have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Roland : $\oplus$ means direct sum. I think it's a quite standard notation as I have seen all text books (which ever I have read) use this.

Comment: @Qwerty: Some books use $\dot{+}$ for the direct sum and $\oplus$ for the orthogonal one, if there is some ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is by using the following fact:

**For a vector space $V$, if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, then their sum $U+V$ is a direct sum if and only if $U \cap W=\{0\}$.**

Now since $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ we have that $\text{im}(T)$ is a subspace of $V$,  and we are given that $W$ is a T-invariant subspace of $V$, so we can make the following conclusion:

$\text{im}(T) \cap W=\{0\}$

Given that $W$ is T-invariant, we have that for any $w\in W$, $T(w)\in W$. But we also know that $T(w)\in \text{im}(T)$. Given that we know their intersection is $\{0\}$ this means that $T(w)=0$, which by definition, means that each $w\in W$ is sent to $0$ by T, and therefore $W\subset N(T)$.

By the rank-nullity theorem we know that $\text{dim}(V)= \text{dim(im}(T))+\text{dim}(N(T))$. Since $V=\text{im}(T) \oplus W$, we also know that $\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim(im}(T)) +\text{dim}(W)$. This tells us that $\text{dim}(W)=\text{dim}(N(T))$.

Since $W\subset N(T)$ and their dimensions are equal, we must have that $W=N(T)$.

Comment: @Qwerty hopefully this clarifies everything.

Comment: yeah it does ... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $w\in W$; then $T(w)\in\operatorname{im}(T)$ by definition and $T(w)\in W$ since $W$ is $T$-invariant. Thus $T(w)=0$; therefore $W\subseteq N(T)$.

Can it be $W\subsetneq N(T)$? Use the fact that, by assumption,
$$
\dim V=\dim \operatorname{im}(T)+\dim W
$$
and that, by the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\dim V=\dim \operatorname{im}(T)+\dim N(T)
$$

Comment: please add a proof of $N(T)\subseteq W$ .I am at a loss as how to to that..

Comment: @Qwerty The dimension of $W$ is equal to $\dim V-\dim\operatorname{im}(T)$ by assumption, which is the same as the dimension of $N(T)$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't accept two answers. The one I accepted is slightly better explained.